# nfsen per IP bandwidth and protocol usage graphs

Tags: monitoring, scripting, ntop

I've been trying to use nTop for the past week and I've gotten a little fed up with the fact that it loses all the data that it's stored after a reboot.

Consequently, while looking for alternatives, I've come across multiple suggestions of nfsen.

Does nfsen allow me to plot, per ip, bandwidth AND protocol usage over time? If it is not supported natively, does someone have scripts that would interpret the netFlow data to demonstrate this? Is it only nTop that can accomplish this?

I've googled this and I've found [vague](http://www.mail-archive.com/nfsen-discuss@lists.sourceforge.net/msg02335.html) [hints](https://serverfault.com/questions/220972/how-to-collect-figures-of-traffic-used-per-host-broken-up-by-time-and-destinati) of people creating their own scripts to accomplish what I want to do. I've got some scripting knowledge (python, perl), but I would rather not invent the wheel. Is anyone willing to share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out nfsen isn't what I need at all. Bandwidthd gives me per IP usage graphs and daily usage totals. The best part is, it can also interact with a postgresql database!

*Oh let me count the ways I love thee Bandwidthd...*